# VS.Net 2013 - Configuration changing the publish setting

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to update the Publish and Application setting based on the configuration setting.  I have added DEV, SIT and UAT to the configuation setting

In my project file, I have update the settings by the following:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'DEV|AnyCPU' ">
  <InstallUrl>http://devserver/App/</InstallUrl>
  <PublishUrl>C:\Projects\DEV\</PublishUrl>
  <ProductName>MyApp – DEV</ProductName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and also tried

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'DEV' ">
      <InstallUrl>http://devserver/App/</InstallUrl>
      <PublishUrl>C:\Projects\DEV\</PublishUrl>
      <ProductName>MyApp – DEV</ProductName>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

As I change the configuration, I was expecting to see to visually see the new settings.

Any ideas why this is not working correctly.

Also, I wanted to change the AssemblyName, but that also does appear to work

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to deploy a Web project,
You should create different publishing profiles based on your configuration settings.

[image: Choose your publishing profile or create a new]

[image: Setup Publish Method]

[image: Setup Publish Build Configuration]

Once you publish for the first time all the information entered in the windows showed above will be saved on the Profile specified on the first tab.

Comment: I see that for web but not for a WPF application.

I will use that for the WCF section